# Blinking cursor shows up when I click on UILabel, coupled with appearance of a keyboard

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, first-responder

I have built a custom UITableView with two cells.  In one cell I have added a UIImageView, in another a UILabel.  when I click on the cell with the UILabel an unwanted keyboard pops up with a blinking cursor.  I have checked to make sure I am not using a duplicate reuse identifier.  Why is this happening?  I thought UILabels don't call  the keyboard.  How can I get rid of this?  Is there a way to access the cell through a delegate method like

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

???

Thanks in advance for your help.  Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:qRViewCellIdentifier];

 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
 if (cell == nil)
 {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:qRViewCellIdentifier] autorelease];

  if (row == kQRRowIndex)
  {
   CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(10,10.0,255.0,255.0);
   UIImageView *qRImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect] autorelease];
   qRImageView.tag = row;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:qRImageView];
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  }
  else
  {
   CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10,10.0,255.0,25.0);
   UILabel *fastPayLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
   fastPayLabel.tag = row;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:fastPayLabel];
  }
 }

 if (row == kQRRowIndex)
 {
  UIImageView *qRImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kQRRowIndex];
  qRImageView.image = [[UserManager sharedUserManager] qRImage];
 }
 else
 {
  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithString:@"Enable Fast Pay"];

  UILabel *fastPayLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:kFastPayRowIndex]; 
  fastPayLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  fastPayLabel.text = message;
  fastPayLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
 }

 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, you have a typo here: `UILabel *fastPayLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];`.
Instead of allocating UILabel object, you're actually allocating UITextField... =)